# how to distinguish that a window popup is opened from normal tab or from a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, window-object

I am working on a chrome extension app, here I am opening a new window(with url:xyz.com) from chrome extension app, and the same codebase is deployed in a server(url:xyz.com) as well as with the same functionality(opening new window popop, url:xyz.com). But unable to distinguish that window popup is opened from normal tab or from a chrome extension.

following is the data flow :

here someurl.com is a third party url.

[image]

Comment: There's no way to know it after the fact. Depending on where exactly in the code you need to know it, you can implement some workarounds.

Comment: since i am opening the popup window with same page url, there only i want to know it. any helpfull suggession would be appreciated.

Comment: What you're asking for is not clear. Where do you want to know if the specific tab has been opened by an extension or not? In the tab itself (code that is on xyz.com) or from your extension?

Comment: I have updated my question for more clarity.